# Browserify a mix of coffeescript and livescript files

Tags: coffeescript, browserify, livescript

I have a main coffee file and a mix of other coffee and livescript files.

```
# main.coffee
require 'LiveScript'
one = require './one.coffee'
two = require './two.ls'
console.log one.fun(), two.fun()

# one.coffee
module.exports.fun = -> 1

# two.ls
module.exports.fun = -> 2
```

I can run

```
coffee main.coffee
```

But trying to run

```
browserify -t coffeeify main.coffee
```

Gives an error:

```
module.exports.fun = -> 2
                      ^
ParseError: Unexpected token >
```

The only workaround I see is to compile ls files to js first.  Is there a simpler, direct way to mix ls and coffee files?

Comment: Use a better tool, maybe :).

Comment: What tool?  Better than what?

Comment: commonjs-everywhere, for example

Answer (score 0):

`require 'LiveScript'` is only sufficient for Node.js. Browserify does not support [`require.extensions`](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_require_extensions), and is trying to parse the LiveScript as JavaScript.

You need a transform for LiveScript as well, for example [Liveify](https://github.com/quarterto/liveify).

Answer (score -1):

You might try [Webpack](http://webpack.github.io/). With proper loaders, e.g. livescript-loader, coffee-loader and others, you can compose your program with different js flavors.